# Hover not working on animated div

Tags: javascript, css

I've made a codepen with a Tweenlite animated box. The box has a :hover in the css.
If you place your mouse in the path of the animated box so it 'hits' the mouse you see the hover effect doesn't happen. It only happens when the mouse moves on it.

How do I fix that?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EfAGn

```
.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:2px;
}

.red {
  background-color:red;
}

.red:hover{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: It does for me on Firefox version 30.0, but not on Chrome 35.0.

Comment: For me in Chrome 35 it only works after the first time the `:hover` event should have triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a continuation of Jcubed's answer:

Essentially it's calculating the mouses position and checking it against the objects position, and then seeing if the distance between the two is less than 25px every 100ms.

If the object is less than 25px (half of the object width) then it is inside of it and will add the hover class. If it is greater it will remove the hover class.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hxBik)

```
(function() {


    $("#restart").on("click", function() {
      tl.restart();
    })
    var mX, mY, distance, mousePosition,
        $distance = $('#distance span'),
        $element  = $('#redBox');
     // Movement
     var tl = new TimelineLite()
     tl.to($element, 15, {x:550});

    setInterval(function() {

       function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
            return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offset().left+(elem.width()/2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
       }

       $(document).mousemove(function(e) {  
           mX = e.pageX;
           mY = e.pageY;
           mousePosition = (mX, mY);
           $distance.text(distance);  
       });
       distance = calculateDistance($element, mX, mY);
       if(distance < 25){
          console.log("Mouse Has Entered");
          //adding hovered class
          $($element).addClass('hovered');
       }

       else{
          // removing hovered class
          $($element).removeClass('hovered');
       }
    // Setting Timeout
    }, 100);
})();
```

[Here's some additional information from Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/calculate-distance-between-mouse-and-element/)

Comment: Thank you MathiasaurusRex - that will do fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a browser bug. It seems that the browser is only reevaluating the hover state when the mouse moves, not when the animation changes.

What you'll need to do is probably to manually check where the box is and where the user's mouse is every frame, and update the css through JavaScript instead of relying on `:hover`.

Or, simply wait for browsers to fix this bug. As @Pondwater pointed out, it works in firefox 30.

Comment: Yup, also applies when you hover over the element and you don't move the mouse, the `:hover` state persists until the mouse is moved.

This issue is a bit deeper, too. On that Codepen, click on the Restart button. Then hover over the element, and don't move the mouse. Wait until the element moves outside of the cursor. Then press Enter to trigger the Restart. The `:hover` state still persists.